# Docker Compose: Import MySQL database into a running docker container from CLI

Tags: mysql, docker, import, docker-compose, devops

After trying various things whatever I do I get certain error messages - I want to import a local SQL file database into a running docker container.

*This is what I try to do:*

```
sudo docker-compose exec project-db mysql -uuser -ppassword database_name < "/localpath/2020-05-03-14_00-hexagon_brainformance.sql"
```

*This is my docker compose file:*

```
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.25
    container_name: "project-db"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
```

*This is what `sudo docker ps` gives me:*

`cb2c5e884c90   mysql:5.7.25   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, :::3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   project-db`

*This is my current error:*

> ERROR: No such service: project-db

Tried various variations with using `db` instead of `project-db` and also with `-it` flag to go into the container first. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd recommend using `mysql -h127.0.0.1` from the host, connecting to the container's published `ports:`.  If you must use `docker-compose exec` then it uses the service name `db`.  (You shouldn't usually need `container_name:`.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Great idea worked like a charm. You need local mysql for this workaround right? Still it solved the problem so be free to make an answer out of it.